# Tuning SQL query if where clause uses non index column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

I have a table `emp` with columns `id, empname, sal, join_date` and I have this query:

```
select * 
from emp
where join_date between date1  and date2 ;
```

Only id has index no other other column has.

How can I tune this query it is on prod and customer don't let me create index or partition on `join_date` column. It takes 5-7 minutes to return just a few rows (10-15). How can I improve performance?

Comment: You cannot without adding a index, the query is pretty straighforward. If you get permission to create an indexed VIEW you can create indexed view from that table

Comment: Customer doesn't let me create an index - what? Does he also go to the doctor and refuse the doc to give him pills to make him better?